# HomeandLearn Calculator: the textDisplay doesn't clear whatsoever when I hit the btnPlus button.

Tags: c#, calculator

I have been following the C# tutorial at http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s2p17.html to make a calculator. I was doing just fine, following the instructions verbatim. I think they have to have an error in the tutorial or something because I have been pulling my freaking hair out trying to figure out why my calculator won't clear text when the + sign is clicked, (which, according to his tutorial, it's supposed to do -- right?)

Here is my code (Note the very bottom when I start to call the double variables, as this is where I "got lost"):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
public partial class calc : Form
{
    public calc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnOne.Text;
    }

    private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnTwo.Text;
    }

    private void btnThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnThree.Text;
    }

    private void btnFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnFour.Text;
    }

    private void btnFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnFive.Text;
    }

    private void btnSix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnSix.Text;
    }

    private void btnSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnSeven.Text;
    }

    private void btnEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnEight.Text;
    }

    private void btnNine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnNine.Text;
    }

    private void btnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnZero.Text;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDisplay.Clear();
    }

    double total1 = 0;
    double total2 = 0;

    private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        txtDisplay.Clear();
    }

    private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        txtDisplay.Text = total2.ToString();
        total1 = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Now, on the next page of the tutorial (http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s2p18.html), it asks me to add in the code for the equal button. It doesn't do anything it should when I run it. Namely, the textDisplay doesn't clear whatsoever when I hit the btnPlus button.

And I went through a lot of other questions attempting to find an answer before posting this. And no, this is not homework. It's a hobby actually.

I'm going crazy guys. Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to give me. I'm sure when this is figured out I'm going to want to slap myself.

Comment: How have you hooked up the event handler for `btnEquals`? It should be in a similar way to how you did it for `btnPlus` (probably by double clicking the button in design view).

Comment: When you click the `btnClear`, does the text clear then?

Comment: Use breakpoints to debug your code - http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: @ElYusubov - How do you debug an event that doesn't fire?

Comment: If something doesn't work the way that you expect it, then you simply put your breakpoints and debug it step-by-step.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to dive back into this until today as I was working most of yesterday.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to dive back into this until today as I was working most of yesterday. @Oded : I set both `btnPlus` and `btnEquals` the same way, by double clicking them. As I understand it, at this point in the process, my calculator should be functioning properly with the originally posted code. I may be misunderstanding your question, however, because I am still very new. @ TyrionLannister : That's the messed up thing, when I hit `btnClear` the text clears exactly as it should! If `txtDisplay.Clear();` is working for `btnClear` why wouldn't it be for `btnPlus`? (Not used to SO Comment)

Comment: When you double click a button, the default action by Visual Studio is to setup an event handler for the click event of the button, with the pattern `<button name>_click`. If you double clicked the `btnEquals` in design view, that should have done everything for you.

Comment: @Oded I must be doing something wrong. I might have to just start over from scratch. I did indeed double click `btnEquals` to set up the event. From what I gather, clicking `btnPlus` should a) store whatever is in `txtDisplay` as a double in a variable called `total1`, and b) clear `txtDisplay`. None of that happens, however. When you click `btnEquals` I gather the program should a) add the first and second number to create total2, which should display the answer to `txtDisplay` and b) reset the first total variable to 0. When you click `btnClear`, the text should clear, that works fine

Comment: It really is not possible to say what is going wrong, not based on the posted code. In the design view, when the button is selected, see if in the properties window (F4) under the click event if the event handler is there. I suspect it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** I would advice to look at debugging tool in Visual Studio. It will help you to understand what is going on when you click the buttons.

Here is a good and simple post to look - [**debugging tutorial**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)

Comment: @EIYusubov : I set breakpoints at a couple of areas with no luck. Everything seems to be coming out fine. I am currently reading the rest of the link you provide which seems useful indeed.

Comment: @JOSHUAPINKHAM, sure no problem. Not sure why you are not able to find issue while debugging. About the reference link, for sure it should help you in long run.

Answer (score 0):

ReWrite the button again,then double click the buttoun from your form,after that try again to press + and see ,think will be sucesfull,wish you good luck

Answer (score -2):

```
private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total1 += total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        txtDisplay.Clear();
    }
```

Just add a "+" before the "=" sign, and it will work.